# Google GSON - Parse html codes

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm using Google GSON library in my android app to parse json response from server.
In some cases API retrieve html codes in response (e.g &#187). Is it possible to tell Google GSON to parse that codes and convert to symbol that associated with that code?

Comment: could you give us a example output from your api?

Comment: Sure

{"Id":8075,"Images":[],"Fields":["Type|15"],"Text":"&#171;Some message&#187;","Phone":"+374 xx-xx-xx"}

Answer (score 0):

Gson does not have anything built in that would do that, no.

The only way to have Gson do this for you would be to write a custom deserializer for `String` that would decode the strings. You'd also need another library to do the HTML decoding since Java itself doesn't include anything.

Here's an example using the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library to do the decoding:

```
public class App 
{
    String foo;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
    {
        String json = "{\"Text\":\"&#171;Some message&#187;\"}";

        Gson g = 
            new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(String.class, new MyStringDeserializer()).create();

        Type t = new TypeToken<Map<String,String>>(){}.getType();
        Map<String,String> map = g.fromJson(json, t);
        System.out.println(map.get("Text"));
    }
}


class MyStringDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<String>
{

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc) throws JsonParseException
    {
        String s = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml3(je.getAsString());
        return s;
    }

}
```

Output:

> «Some message»